# How To Pause/Stop Updating Geolocation in UWP C#

Tags: c#, geolocation, win-universal-app

I'm trying to stop tracking my location from a button. Does anyone know how to do this? I tried to unsubscribe from the positionChanged event but "It doesn't exist in the current context" (from inside my stop button event)

```
        private void StopTrakBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        geolocator1.PositionChanged -= Geolocator_PositionChanged;
    }
```

Maybe I'm going about this all wrong. Anyone able to help?

Comment: It looks that you are reference something in a different xaml page, so you get this error. Your code is right to me for "StopTracking" button, maybe you can share more information.

Comment: I'm going to try to initialize the geolocator outside of the TrackMyLocation(); function. Maybe that will do it. I will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

I`ve seen that, besides unsubscribing, if I set the ReportInterval to 0, it does not trigger updates:

```
locator.ReportInterval = default(uint)
```